# CGI perl read and print the content of a file

Tags: cgi, perl-module

I wanted to open a text file and read the first 10 line by using `CGI` and `Perl`
I wrote the script but it does not work. where is my problem

```
#!C:/wamp/apps/Perl/bin/perl.exe -wt

use CGI;
my $cgi=CGI->new();

print 
$cgi->header('text/html'),
$cgi->start_html('Extract the text'),
$cgi->h1({-style=>'color:red;background-color:#eee;'},'Extract CGI'),
$cgi->start_form(-enctype=>&CGI::MULTIPART),
'Upload your text File: ',
$cgi->filefield(
    -name=>'filename',
    ),
$cgi->submit(-value=>'Read the File'),

my $txtfile=$cgi->param('filename'),

open my $in,$filename or die("couldnot open");
while (my $line = <$in>)
{
    print $line;
    last if $. == 10;
}
close $in;

$cgi->end_form;
$cgi->end_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might find this useful

http://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl-2/

basically, the file uploaded is not named the same as the file passed in from the browser

You need to do some checks on what you've been sent first

Comment: this from page '2 6. Getting the File Handle

As I mentioned above, we can use the upload method to grab the file handle of the uploaded file (which actually points to a temporary file created by CGI.pm). We do this like so:

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");' So CGI has already saved the file, you just need to consume the file and save it or do other things with it